# How to display the name of a related model in symfony1.4

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I've got a symfony admin model that has a related field (doctrine). In the admin list view it displays the ID instead of the name. How can I change this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I remember correctly, you can use the name of the relation as fieldname in the displaylist.

But what always works is using a partial. So in your generator.yml:

```
list:
  display: [id, name, _referred]
```

And then created `_referred.php` in your templates folder, and do something like:

`<?php echo $modelName->Referred->name; ?>`

Answer (score 0):

I see that you already have an accepted answer, but will answer anyway:

Create a `__toString()` method in the related model. Symfony will automatically use it to output that object, and thus displaying what you want.